# Token in header (cURL) with Express.js Node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, curl, express, restful-authentication

So, I want to use this code in my project:

```
var allowCrossTokenHeader = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "token");
};
```

But it does not work, the server hangs and does not work, if I comment this code the server is working correctly. I need to check a token in each request to my RESTful api, any idea how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `next()` for it to continue to the next middleware in the stack.

```
var allowCrossTokenHeader = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "token");
    next();
};
```

> If the current middleware does not end the request-response cycle, it must call next() to pass control to the next middleware, otherwise the request will be left hanging.

[Documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: thank you! and other question, for this function: var allowMethods = function(req, res, next) { res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"); }; I need to call next()?

Comment: You need to call `next()` for **all** middleware that doesn't return a response to the client.